# Linked List data structure with Java's list interface

Tags: java, generics, linked-list

Suppose we have the following declaration of a Java class `Cell<T>` used for
constructing singly linked lists:

```
class Cell<T> {

    T first;
    Cell<T> next;

    Cell(T f, Cell<T> n) {
        first = f;
        next = n;
    }
}
```

**Question 1.**
Explain how a linked list data structure consisting of `Cell<T>` objects could be used to implement
the Java interface `List<E>`. An explanation in English, possibly with diagrams, is sufficient, you
are not required to write the Java code for the implementation to answer this question.

**Attempt (Question 1).**
No clue where to start with this question to be honest. Maybe if we had a linked list data strucutre consiting of `Cell<T>` objects we could use an ArrayList?

**Question 2.**
Java’s `List<E>` interface has a method remove with the following signature:

```
public E remove(int i)
```

Write the Java code which gives this method for the implementation described in question 1.

**Attempt (Question 2).**
Well because I don't understand question 1, nor could I provide an explanation I don't know how to do this one.

**Question 3.**
Write a Java method which takes a Cell object representing a linked list and returns an array which is of the length of the linked list and contains the elements of the linked list in the order they
occur in the list.

**Attempt (Question 3).**
I was provided with a solution for this question by my teacher but he didn't explain it well enough. So if someone could explain the solution to me that would be great, I don't understand the iteration through the loop part:

```
for (Cell<T> ptr = list; ptr != null; ptr = ptr.next)
```

**Solution (Question 3).**

```
public static <T> T[] question3(Cell<T> c) {
    int count = 0;
    for (Cell<T> ptr = list; ptr != null; ptr = ptr.next) {
        count++;
    }
    T[] arr = (T[]) new Object[count];
    int i = 0;
    for (Cell<T> ptr = list; ptr != null; ptr = ptr.next;i++){
    arr[i] = ptr.first;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Please only ask *one* question, not three in one.

Comment: The first two are actually one question on the paper I've split it into two to make it easier to read, but yes I will avoid asking more than one question in the future.

Comment: Having a cons-Cell implement List is problematic, but there *is* a [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) (which does *not* use an ArrayList) which implements List using a linked list internally. The implementation in either case comes down to what "a linked list data structure" means (a cons list or a wrapper around such).

Comment: Don't you think it's better to learn about `LinkedList` data structure from google rather than posting your entire question paper here ? ;) Have a look at this singly linked list implementation [example](http://crunchify.com/how-to-implement-a-linkedlist-class-from-scratch-in-java/)

Comment: In any case, to remove a cell at an index requires iterating from the start of the list and then 'fixing' the previous element skip the element to remove. Special casing needs to be done for the first element (which can't be removed and must remain as *the* object representing the start of the list, as `remove` is void).

Comment: I don't think `Cell` is a usable basis for implementing `List`, or any other defined functionality, because `first` and `next` are not private.

Answer (score 0):

1) Think about the meaning of "implementing the interface" - (read the documentation if you need to) - what do you need to do in order to achieve that?
2) once you understand Q1) it will not be a problem for you.
3) Look into `iterators`